# Can't connect to mysql server on 'localhost' (10061) after replacing localhost at etc/hosts

Tags: mysql, django, wampserver

I am adding the **facebook authentication** to my django application using the link http://goo.gl/hQ5nx5. I am using **Wampserver** for **Mysql**. There's a direction in the above link at step-4 to add an entry in the `C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts` file that maps `127.0.0.1` to something like `test1.com`. But after this when I run my server through cmd, it gives the error: `Can't connect to mysql server on 'localhost' (10061)`.

Kindly suggest me the solution to this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Is your settings.py pointing at localhost?  You could adjust it
   to point to test1.com, but that's likely to then cause issues when
   you change back, so a better answer is:
2. /etc/hosts supports multiple hostnames for an ip address.  You probably want a line like

   127.0.0.1 localhost test1.com